# Java bug on Mac OSX?

Tags: java, macos, swing, timer, actionlistener

Good evening all,
I have this simple piece of code I ran today and found an odd behavior on the Mac OSX Operating System (Mountain Lion). Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Prog33_01
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Timer t = new Timer(1000, new CurrentTime());
         t.start();

       //Exception safe code
        Thread.sleep(5000);

     }
}
```

And then the `CurrentTime()` class.

```
class CurrentTime implements ActionListener
{

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    System.out.println("Time is: " + new Date() );
}

}
```

This is a very simple program and runs as expected on Windows 7. But on the Mac OSX, using Netbeans and the latest Java 7 u15. The time keeps running. Is there something wrong in here.

Comment: What did you expect the behavior to be?

Comment: There should be 5 prints of the current Date, then the program would exit. On Mac OSX, the Date just keeps on printing out, well over the 5 second sleep() count.

Comment: Could this just be a difference in implementations?  When I read the [API for Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) is doesn't mention anything about when the Timer should stop executing.

Comment: Nothing in the documentation actually specifies if the timer thread is a daemon or not.

Comment: From the documentation: "_After this first event, it continues to fire events every time the between-event delay has elapsed, until it is stopped_."  This makes me wonder if the bug is in the Windows JVM...  Actually [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7641292/778118) explains what's happening clearly.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the logic that specifically terminates the thread after an arbitratal number of times.

Comment: Im coming from a Windows C++ background and I would have imagine that calling Thread.sleep(5000) merely delays the current running thread for 5 seconds, then continues execution to the exit of the main function, which in turn terminated the program. @jahroy, That exaplanation does clear the why, but then how exactly am I to modify my program if I AM using a Swing GUI for instance? importing java.util.Timer with javax.swing.Timer causes chaos apparently.

Comment: Can you just stop the Timer yourself using `Timer.stop()`?

Comment: @gandolf - If you're coding a Swing App then use `javax.swing.Timer`, as it will be terminated when the app closes. If you are coding a standalone app then use `java.util.Timer`, or a scheduled thread executor.

Comment: Well here was my not-so-elegant fix. After much reading the comments on this, I decided the easiest thing to do in my case was to call System.exit(0); after the thread.sleep() call. The reasoning behind this was because the Timer is created with Swing, after the Thread.sleep() count, the EDT is still alive, so in order to destroy it, and therefore destroying the Timer, one has to call exit() to exit the application. For larger projects though, I will keep in mind to use the appropriate Timer.