# ActionListener implementation with lambda expression doesn't work invoked by a Timer

Tags: java, lambda

I am reading the book [Core Java Vol 1] 10th edition and in chapter 6 section 6.3.6 there is a code snippet for explaining "Variable Scope" in lambda expression.I ran this code on my own and it just terminated immediately and not showing "Hello" every 2 seconds as expected in console log.

I am using jdk1.8.0_202 and here is my code:

```
package variableScope;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

public class VariableScopeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        repeatMessage("Hello", 2000);
    }

    private static void repeatMessage(String text, int delay) {
        ActionListener listener = event -> {
            System.out.println(text);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        };
        new Timer(delay, listener).start();
    }
}
```

Any explanation why this doesn't work? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swing timer persistence after main method finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641236/swing-timer-persistence-after-main-method-finishes)

Comment: If you think lambdas were the problem, did you try removing them and seeing how your code works then?

Comment: @Torben Yeah, I was just thinking to do it after my post. I think i just ask in here too hurry. I will pay more attention next time. I am new to this community. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with lambda and all to do with there being no Swing event thread. You need to display a Swing GUI for the event thread to run; something as simple as a JOptionPane would work. A Timer alone will not do.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;    
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            repeatMessage("Hello", 2000);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "foo"); // starts the thread
        });

    }

    private static void repeatMessage(String text, int delay) {
        ActionListener listener = event -> {
            System.out.println(text);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        };
        new Timer(delay, listener).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: @NiYilun glad it did, but the other comments had a decent point -- if you thought it was the lamba, why didn't you try it without the lambda? You'd see immediately that your assumption was incorrect. You need to play with your code more, especially more before coming here.

Comment: Yeah, I was just thinking to do it after my post. I think i just ask in here too hurry. I will pay more attention next time. I am new to this community. Should I delete this post?